How to Change Header Color in Streamlit DataFrame Display?
I'm working on a Streamlit app where I display a DataFrame using st.dataframe. I want to change the color of the header row (for example, making the "Market," "Metro Quota," and "Metro BTS" headers different colors). However, I haven't been able to find a way to apply these styles directly in Streamlit.
I've tried using pandas Styler to apply styles, but the colors don’t show up when the DataFrame is displayed in Streamlit. Here’s a simplified version of my code and a screenshot of the current DataFrame display:

I am requesting to change the color of header row.
Note: DataFrame is combination of multiple excel files and converted into single "filtered_df" dataframe which is being displayed on the streamlit web app as mentioned in the image.
here is code which might help you:
 # Initialize filtered dataframe
filtered_df = result_df
float_cols = filtered_df.select_dtypes(include=['float']).columns
filtered_df[float_cols] = filtered_df[float_cols].fillna(0)
filtered_df[float_cols] = filtered_df[float_cols].apply(lambda col: col.round().astype(int))

# Display the dataframe with filtering logic
with st.expander("Dataframe", expanded=True):
    if selected_market == "All":
        filtered_df.style
        st.data_editor(filtered_df, height=350, use_container_width=True, hide_index=True)
    else:
        filtered_df = filtered_df[(filtered_df['Market'] == selected_market) | (filtered_df['Market'] == selected_market + " Total")]
        st.data_editor(filtered_df, use_container_width=True, hide_index=True)

# Add a button to save the filtered DataFrame as a CSV file
if st.button('Save Finalized Data'):
    # Save the filtered dataframe (either whole or filtered by the selected market)
    filtered_df.to_excel('finalized_goals.xlsx', index=False)
    st.success('Filtered data has been saved successfully!')


st.dataframe and st.data_editor do not allow styling like this.
Using pandas styler is definitely the way to go to change the color of the header row.
We can then display the styled dataframe using st.table.
Note that st.table looses some interactivity features of st.dataframe and does not support editing like st.data_editor.
I don't think there is a perfect solution if you need an editable data frame (I know you asked about st.dataframe but your example is using st.data_editor).
Here is an example:
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Market": ["Alabama", "Alabama"],
        "Store": ["15TH ST", "DEMOPOLIS"],
        "Metro Quota": [187, 81],
        "Metro BTS": [58, 35],
    }
)

styled_df = df.style.set_table_styles(
    [
        {"selector": "th:nth-child(2)", "props": [("background-color", "yellow")]},
        {"selector": "th:nth-child(4)", "props": [("background-color", "pink")]},
        {"selector": "th:nth-child(5)", "props": [("background-color", "orange")]},
    ]
)

st.table(styled_df)



I tried this but for my case its not working.

Can you elaborate?
